# How to add additional information to the Twilio connect object

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, twilio-twiml

I create a call with Twilio REST API and I have a Twilio JS client which receives this call among other calls created by other parties. **I need a way to distinguish my call among other calls in Twilio JS client.**

When the call (which was created by Twilio REST API) is connected, Twilio makes a request to my app and I provide Twilio with TwiML instructions to route the call to the Twilio JS client.

I need to add custom information in connection to be able to **detect in Twilio JS client whether the call was created by Twilio REST API**. I see two points where I should be able to add custom information to the call:

1. when I create a call with Twilio REST API
2. when I provide Twilio with further TwiML instructions

This works in JS SDK.

```
params = {
        "MyCustomField": "my data",
        ... 
    };
 Twilio.Device.connect(params);
```

There is a "message" object in the "connection" object (Twilio JS SDK):

```
{
"_maxListeners": 0,
"_events": {...},
"device": {...},
"message": {
    MyCustomField: "my data",
      ...
},
"options": {...},
"parameters": {
    "ApiVersion": "2010-04-01",
    "CallSid": "...",
    "From": "...",
    "To": "client:client59",
    "AccountSid": "..."
},
"_status": "closed",
"_direction": "INCOMING",
"sendHangup": false,
"_publisher": {...},
"_monitor": {...},
"mediaStream": {...},
"outboundConnectionId": "...",
"pstream": {...}
}
```

The question is how to add data to this object by Twilio REST API or TwiML?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

That `message` property is an undocumented property, so I wouldn't necessarily rely on it. In this case it's used to pass those parameters to your TwiML application via the webhook.

There is no way to pass data through to a Client instance like this from the API request or the TwiML. You might be able to use the [`statusCallback` events](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/client#attributes-status-callback) to achieve something here, but I'm not entirely sure what your overall goal is here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The overall goal is to distinguish generated calls from organic one on the client without an additional ajax request to the server. Calls that was created by my app should be immediately connected to the JS client, while all other organic calls shouldn't be immediately connected (user should have an opportunity to make a decision whether he/she wants to answer or ignore the call). Could you please suggest a solution?

Comment: Can I setup my Twilio.Device to use more than 1 client name? I mean that one Twilio.Device will be connected to calls routed to "client:firstclient" or "client:secondclient"? I can't have multiple instances of  Twilio.Device on the same page, can I?

Comment: If calls created by the app should be immediately connected, why not make those calls from Twilio Client itself? Then all inbound calls will be organic calls.

Comment: It is not an option because the call can be AnsweredByMachine and in such cases, there are no needs to route calls to the user, we play instead pre-recorded audio. Taking into account that almost half of our call is answered by a machine, we call multiple numbers for each available user. For example for 2 agents, I create 4 calls. If I do it on the backend it doesn't matter which of these calls will be answered by human while it is only 2 calls were answered. If I call on frontend it is possible that first agent gets 2 connected calls, while the second one gets none.

Comment: Right now I mark calls before routing to JS client. On the client in Twilio.Device.incoming handler I make ajax request and by connection.parameters.CallSid detect whether it is a generated call. Because of this additional request, I have an additional second of delays before the generated call is accepted. I hope it is more clear now. Could you please suggest any solutions to avoid this delays?

Comment: Have you checked out [TaskRouter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter)? It lets you setup different workflows for calls, routes calls to available agents and allows for custom attributes to be set on Tasks within the system.